# How to get the count of season subscribed from wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I have a query

```
SELECT um.user_id 
FROM wp_season_user_trans ut 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um 
ON um.meta_value='member' 
and ut.user_id = um.user_id 
group by um.user_id.
```

i want the count of subscribed persons who are members from usermeta table.

From usermeta table i am getting 10 members. when i join with other table also i am not getting the same result.